# Find the output value using call by value and call by reference

Tags: programming-languages, java

Given the following code:
int p = 5 , q=2;
int f( int b, int c){
b = 2 * c;
c = 3 + p;
return b + c ;}
print f(p,q);
print p;
print q;

I have found that the output values using call by value are:
f(p,q)=12
p=5
q=2

And as far as i know also the output using call by reference in this example ,gives the same values.Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both by value:

```
{p = 5, q = 2, b = 5, c = 2}
b= 2 * c; 
{p = 5, q = 2, b = 4, c = 2} 
c= 3 + p; 
{p = 5, q = 2, b = 4, c = 8}
return b + c;
{b + c = 12}
```

Both by reference:

```
{p = b = 5, q = c = 2}
b= 2 * c; 
{p = b = 4, q = c = 2}
c= 3 + p; 
{p = b = 4, q = c = 7}
return b + c;
{b + c = 11}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,its very helpful.

Comment: int n = 3; 
  int m = 9; 
  public void f(int x, int y){
      int n = 5; 
      x = n; 
      m = y - 2; }
  public static void main(String[] args){ 
     f(m, n); 
     System.out.println(n); 
     System.out.println(m); }
I have found that the output value using call by value are 3 and 1 and using call by reference the values are 5 an 1. Am i right?